# HTML5/JavaScript Canvas Text Gradient Effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there a way to apply a gradient to a text inside a canvas using **HTML5**/**JavaScript** only?

`<canvas id="myCanvas">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
 </canvas>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 50);

ctx.font = "30px Verdana";
// Create gradient
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, 0);
gradient.addColorStop("0", "magenta");
gradient.addColorStop("0.5", "blue");
gradient.addColorStop("1.0", "red");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 90);

</script>
```

Comment: May I borrow your good code and add some compositing to make your text become gradient? http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/mt1x0wkL/

Comment: this was nice. But i forgot something to mention. I need the gradient to be horizontal. Sorry xD

Comment: The example does show a horizontal gradient...Did you mean you need a vertical gradient? Anyway, createLinearGradient defines the startingX, startingY, endingX, and endingY coordinates that the gradient extends through. So you can make the gradient span at any angle by appropriately defining your coordinates. Here's the same example using vertical coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2t4qjwpj/

Comment: @markE. Thank for the example and a little discussion about createLinearGradient. It really helps. Thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Try This using css.

```
 p{
 font-size: 72px;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  }
```

Comment: i'm not allowed to use css :(

Comment: Using only HTML5 i think it is not possible you have to use some script for creating gradient.